# ManyToMany in Hibernate without composite keys

Tags: hibernate, hsqldb, many-to-many, composite-key

I am dealing with legacy database. And I am writing unit test using pojos & hibernate & **HSQLDB**. And I am getting the following error:

```
17:09:03,946 ERROR SchemaExport:349 - Attempt to define a second primary key in statement
```

Let's say I have `Post` and `Tag` entities (and of course their tables `posts` and `tags`). And there is another table to define many-to-many between `Post` and `Tag` called `post_tags`.

Because `post_tags` contains some extra information about the relation, like `active` and `deleted` columns. I created another Entity called `PostTag` to handle this.

To describe my problem here are the pseudo classes:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="post_tags")
public class PostTag {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;

    @ManyToOne
    private Post post;

    @ManyToOne
    private Tag tag;

    // setters and getters
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "tags")
public class Tag {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "tags",cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE})
    private Set<Post> posts;

    // setters and getters
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "posts")
public class Post {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;

    @ManyToMany
    @Cascade({org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE})
    @JoinTable(name = "post_tags", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "post_id") }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "tag_id") })
    private Set<Tag> tags;

    // setters and getters
}
```

When I look at the statement that generates the error it seems Hibernate is trying to make a composite key using `PRIMARY KEY (post_id, tag_id)`, and also it tries to make `post_id` `identity`.

Can anyone help me to fix my problem?

UPDATE:

Because I am dealing with a legacy database this was just an example to demonstrate the problem. But I will try to translate the actual statement according to the example (PS: It is not `ALTER TABLE` it is a `CREATE TABLE`):

```
create table post_tags (id integer not null, post integer, tag integer, post_id integer generated by default as identity (start with 1), tag_id integer not null, primary key (post_id, tag_id)
```

Comment: Can you please post the ALTER TABLE line, too? The one which causes the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the @Id in the class `PostTag`: It tells hibernate that you want a generated identity colum. At the same time, you're saying "I want a composite key" with the mapping of the `tags` field in the class `Posts`.

Which one do you want? Hibernate can't tell.

There is a very good example on page 304 in the book "Java Persistence with Hibernate". [It's on Google books](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&ct=res&cd=2&url=http%3A%2F%2Fbooks.google.ch%2Fbooks%3Fid%3DbTwfHzMxtQcC%26pg%3DPA304%26lpg%3DPA304%26dq%3Dhibernate%2B%2522link%2Btable%2Bwith%2Badditional%2Bcolumns%2522%26source%3Dbl%26ots%3DDqfXPhWKJE%26sig%3DVIk4tGPOwDmKkNnMNs2V6ry5v9M%26hl%3Dde%26ei%3D9FUdStPTBaasjAek3Jm6DQ%26sa%3DX%26oi%3Dbook_result%26ct%3Dresult%26resnum%3D2&ei=9FUdStPTBaasjAek3Jm6DQ&usg=AFQjCNHDdokxpdzlvwHZCJxwp1TAOVmKfQ&sig2=pBGr_cPfU4KNB9ehBbR2eg).

If you don't want the composite key, then you must treat the link table as real objects and use `PostTag` in the class `Posts` (i.e. `Set<PostTag> postTags` instead of `Set<Tag> tags`)

Comment: Well, I do not want a composite key. How do I do the ManyToMany mapping without composite key?